# Prevent Excel from converting 450 to a date?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, format, date-format

Excel is converting `450` to a date when typing 450 into a cell. The date is `3/25/1901`. Why is this, and how can it be prevented?

I formatted the cell, but it reverts to date type every time I type in `450`. Even prefixing with a space (`" 450"`) doesn't solve it.

Here is what I'm trying:

1. Type `450` into cell, it's changed to a date
2. Clear out the cell
3. "Format Cells" on the entire column, set to General
4. Type `450` in again, it becomes a date again

Comment: Do you have any worksheet_events that may be forcing the format back to a date on the change of the data in a cell?

Comment: Do you have neighbouring cells that are formatted as "date"? That might be an explanation, I have no solution though - other than using "format cells" after the entry.

Answer (score -1):

It's simply because those cells have been formatted as date. After that any input data will be treated as date

To fix just select the cells, right click on them and select "Format cells" (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) and choose the Category as General or Number

[image: Format cells]

Comment: As indicated, I've done this. As soon as I type 450 into the cell, it reverts back to a date type.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which clearly states that the cell has not been formatted as a date.